# If statement doesn't break out of loop as I would expect

Tags: python

This is my function code so far (where the error is likely happening):

```py
def showAddition():
    print("You have selected: \"Addition\"")
            
    while True:
        last_answer = None
        if last_answer:
            next_num = int(input("Please input another number: "))
            answer = calc.addNums(last_answer, next_num)
        else:
            num1 = int(input("Please enter your first number: "))
            num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: "))
            answer = calc.addNums(num1, num2)
                
            print(f'Your answer is {answer}')
            continue_prompt = input("Would you like to continue? Y/N\n")
                    
            if continue_prompt.upper() == "Y" or continue_prompt.upper() == "YES":
                last_answer = answer
            else:
                break
```

I was trying to make it so that I could enter another number immediately and add number after number without fail. However, for some reason, the loop simply repeats. It doesn´t even break, even if I input "no" into the continue prompt. Both "yes" and "no" result in the exact same result, and i don't get it.

Comment: You are only checking for “N” and breaking if there is no previous answer.   You could move the print and all subsequent lines out of the else (unindent it).

Answer (score 0):

```py
def showAddition():
    print("You have selected: \"Addition\"")
    
    # store the result of the previous addition
    last_answer = None
    # to stop the loop
    continue_adding = True
    
    while continue_adding:
        if last_answer:
            next_num = int(input("Please input another number: "))
            # answer = last_answer + next_num
            answer = calc.addNums(last_answer, next_num)
            print(f'Your answer is {answer}')
            # store new value in last answer
            last_answer = answer
        else:
            num1 = int(input("Please enter your first number: "))
            num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: "))
            # answer = num1 + num2 
            answer = calc.addNums(num1, num2)
                
            print(f'Your answer is {answer}')
            
            # check input
            while True:
                continue_prompt = input("Would you like to continue? Y/N\n")
                # continue addition directly with stored last_answer
                if continue_prompt.upper() in {"Y","YES"}:
                    last_answer = answer
                    break
                elif continue_prompt.upper() in {"N","NO"}:
                    # stop the loop
                    continue_adding = False
                    break
                else:
                    # ask again to only input Y/N
                    print("Only Enter Either Y/N")
                    continue
```

1. `store` the last answer into the variable above while loop so it won't `reset`
2. set loop variable `continue_loop` used to stop while loop without over coding the inputs if it's not `Y`/`N`
3. Instead of using `if x == y` use `set` or `list` look ups: `if x in [x,y,z]`

Answer (score 0):

As well as Razumov's suggestion to correct the indentation, notice that the "Input another number" block will never run, because `last_answer` is reset to None at the start of each iteration of the while loop. Lets only set that to None at the very start...

If it is your intention to report an accumulating sum throughout the loop, try this:

```py
class calc:
    @staticmethod
    def addNums(*args):
        return sum(args)


def showAddition():
    print("You have selected: \"Addition\"")

    last_answer = None
    while True:
        if last_answer:
                        next_num = int(input("Please input another number: "))
            answer = calc.addNums(last_answer, next_num)
        else:
            num1 = int(input("Please enter your first number: "))
            num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: "))
            answer = calc.addNums(num1, num2)

        print(f'Your answer is {answer}')
        continue_prompt = input("Would you like to continue? Y/N\n")

        if continue_prompt.upper() == "Y" or continue_prompt.upper() == "YES":
            last_answer = answer
        else:
            break
```

(You did not supply the implementation of `calc.addNums`, I added in an implementation so I could run the code).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this if you assume that any response other than N when asking about continuation means that the process should continue.

Always validate numeric input.

For example:

```
class calc:
    @staticmethod
    def addNums(*args):
        return sum(args)

def proceed() -> bool:
    while True:
        yn = input("Do you wish to continue Y/N: ").upper()
        if yn in {"Y", "N"}:
            return yn == "Y"
        print("\aPlease respond with Y or N")

def getint(prompt: str) -> int:
    while True:
        x = input(prompt)
        try:
            return int(x)
        except ValueError:
            print(f"\a'{x}' is not a valid integer")

def showAddition():
    print("You have selected: \"Addition\"")
    total = getint("Please enter your first number: ")
    while True:
        num = getint("Please enter the next value: ")
        total = calc.addNums(total, num)
        print(f"Current {total=}")
        if not proceed():
            break
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using a boolean variable instead of a break down the 2 levels?

i.e.

```
def showAddition():
    print("You have selected: \"Addition\"")
        
    continueProcess = True    
    while continueProcess:
        last_answer = None
        if last_answer:
            next_num = int(input("Please input another number: "))
            answer = calc.addNums(last_answer, next_num)
        else:
            num1 = int(input("Please enter your first number: "))
            num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: "))
            answer = calc.addNums(num1, num2)
                
            print(f'Your answer is {answer}')
            continue_prompt = input("Would you like to continue? Y/N\n")
                    
            if continue_prompt.upper() == "Y" or continue_prompt.upper() == "YES":
                last_answer = answer
            else:
                continueProcess = False
```